# OpenGL extension glBufferData expects 2 istead of 4 arguments

Tags: opengl, glew

I'm using glext.h (http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/ABI/glext.h) to access the OpenGL buffer functions for a windows forms application.

```
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC myglGenBuffers = PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC myglBindBuffer = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC myglBufferData = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC myglDeleteBuffer = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glDeleteBuffer");
```

They all seem to work, except for glBufferData. myglBufferData expects

```
(GLsizei, GLuint *)
```

instead of

```
(GLenum, GLsizeiptr, const GLvoid *, GLenum)^
```

as input arguments and I can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Unfortunately, using GLEW is not an option.

^glBufferData Specification

Comment: You say using GLEW is not an option, but are you aware that the script GLEW uses to generate the headers from extension specifications is available on the GLEW site? You could save yourself a lot of frustration if you used that, you could run it on the VBO extension for instance and all of your prototypes, enumerants, typedefs etc. would be generated for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy paste error?

PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC should be PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC (etc for others)?

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me nuts.